# Massively moving favorites from one folder to another in Google Chrome Version 73.0.3683.86 (64 bits)

Tags: google-chrome

I want to massively move a bunch of favorites found with a search from one favorite folder to another, in Google Chrome Version 73.0.3683.86 (64 bits). Drag and drop isnt working and I tried to find the Google Chrome favorite folder in the root but it seems all the favorites are packed in one file. How can this be done?

Answer (score 1):

## The hand method

Open the Bookmarks Manager putting this in the address bar: chrome://bookmarks/

Select Menu -> Export Bookmarks.

Pick a place to put the file.

Open the file in TextWrangler, Notepad, or your favourite text editor that *doesn't* support HTTP. Make sure Word wrap is off for your sanity. You could also open this file in Chrome and use the Inspector to make this change I guess.

Hit Ctrl+F and look for the source folder name lets call it '*Source*'. It should be on a line that looks a lot like this:

```
<DT><H3 ADD_DATE="*some numbers" LAST_MODIFIED="*some numbers*">*Source*</H3>
        <DL><p>
            <DT><A HREF="chrome://bookmarks/" ADD_DATE="1554473476"
```

The last line shown is the opening words of a bookmark. The first line is of a folder. You can simply move around this data by cutting and pasting them under other folder lines.

Delete the folders you have in your Bookmark manager, or simply erase the bookmarks file
at %USER%\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default

Go back to the bookmark manager and re-import your bookmarks.

## The app method

If it's going to be easier with drag and drop support, just download this extension.

https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwjMu-_Dk7nhAhW1WxUIHQU7DlYQFjAAegQIAhAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Fchrome.google.com%2Fwebstore%2Fdetail%2Fbookmark-manager%2Fidakfiahffeejfhghndaboolmmhbnepn&usg=AOvVaw00unx2IXb3Qx4wfvWi9GwC